# How to return a value with condition from array, with same shape as input array?

Tags: arrays, r

I have this array :

```
arr <- array(data = c(0.1, 0.52, 0.3, 0.4, 0.15, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8), dim = c(2, 2, 2)) 


  > arr
         , , 1

             [,1] [,2]
        [1,] 0.10  0.3
        [2,] 0.52  0.4

       , , 2

            [,1] [,2]
       [1,] 0.15  0.7
       [2,] 0.20  0.8
```

I want to test if there is a value > 0.5 in corresponding values from arr[,,1] and [,,2] so return it if not return NA. 
apply to 0.10 ; 0.15 (return in this case NA as none of them > 0.5) then go to 0.3;0.7 (return 0.7 as it is on of the elements > 0.5) etc

my desire output 1 matrix 2*2:

```
 res1= #resturn the value
       [,1] [,2]
[1,]    NA    0.7
[2,]    0.52    0.8
```

and another matrix 2*2 to show the index 
res2= return the index of that value

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    NA   1
[2,]    1    2
```

1 means 0.7 comes from the first matrix arr[,,1]

2 means 0.8 comes from the second matrix arr[,,2]  etc

Comment: To be clear, you don't just want to know if `which(arr>0.5)` is non-empty. You want to return **an array with the same shape, with NAs substituted wherever arr<=a**. I edited your title to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks @smci no not really. I do not want to return the same array with the same shape. But I want to apply to all elements not one by one so for example: apply to 0.10; 0.3  (return in this case NA as none of them > 0.5) then go to 0.3;0.7 (return 0.7 as it is on of the elements > 0.5) etc.

Comment: Tpellim then what's wrong with simply doing `which(arr>0.1)`, `which(arr>0.3)` ... or even `for (a in seq(0.1,1.9,0.2)) { which(arr>a) }` ... Please state more clearly what the output should be and what shape it should have, for all steps of a?

Comment: I want to apply exactly like this`mxd=apply(arr, c(1, 2), sum)` but instead of summing, look if there is >0.5. The output is one matrix 2*2 same shape yes right.

Comment: Ok but you don't want the output to just be the 1D vector returned by `which(arr>0.5)`. Can you please fix the title to express what you're looking for?

Comment: Why is there an `NA` in the indices?

Comment: Because there is NA in `res1`

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: An index cannot be `NA`, can it?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:: This is an overly hacky solution:**

```
df2<-as.data.frame(arr)
df3<-as.data.frame(apply(df2,2,function(x)ifelse(x>0.5,x,NA)))
mat<-as.matrix(df3[,purrr::map_lgl(df3,~sum(is.na(.x))<=1)])
row(mat)
```

Results:

```
> mat
       V1  V4
[1,]   NA 0.7
[2,] 0.52 0.8
> row(mat)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
```

**ORIGINAL**:

We could use `plyr`:

```
plyr::aaply(arr,c(1,2),function(x) ifelse(x>0.5,x,NA))
```

Result:

```
, ,  = 1

   X2
X1     1  2
  1   NA NA
  2 0.52 NA

, ,  = 2

   X2
X1   1   2
  1 NA 0.7
  2 NA 0.8
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Edited albeit with a very hacky solution.

Comment: Thanks `mat` corresponds to what I wanted but the corresponding indices are not right. they should be index in the original `arr`. `1 means 0.7 comes from the first matrix arr[,,1]`

`2 means 0.8 comes from the second matrix arr[,,2]` etc